# Alternative ways to Pivot Access data using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, pivot

Good day to all.
For the past 8hrs, I am looking for a pivot alternative in Access 2007 since the reference `dll` is not available in our Citrix account (OWC10.dll). So I did all the effort I could do to research workaround on this but I have nothing so far, so I think its time for a little help.

What I have here is a sample of the raw data..

[image]

This is the end result I am looking for, a pivot table, in which of course, can be viewed in a form (best solution) or to an extracted excel file.

[image]

[image]

So basically, I need to display:

- how much time they worked each day
- how many they worked each day.

I tried the [TRANSFORM Statement/Crosstab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192901.aspx) and I get the error that there is too much rows to make it a column since I do have 20,000+ rows - 30days/month * people who worked. - **`DISTINCT` them, but I dont know how?**

I don't have the `.dll` file in our system, so normal pivoting is out of question. Does anyone know any alternatives that can give me these display results?

Comment: Please add the TRANSFORM query you tried to your question. --- How many distinct days do you have in the data (do a query `SELECT DISTINCT ProcessDate FROM yourTable` and scroll to the bottom)?

Comment: Sorry, I only got the code from google and put it in a module then used it like this `Print Transforms("Table","column")` for what I remember, it loops through all the fields in this column and add it as a new column. since its too many, it returns that error - its from microsoft site, cant find it again tho.
I have not really studied crosstab as I am still looking for alternatives. But to answer your question, distinct days depends on how many works people did in that day. E.g my current raw data has 25k rows for the month of June.

Comment: Unless SQL Server is an option, there isn't really anything else than Crosstab queries or Pivot tables (which are deprecated anyway after Access 2010). I suggest you create a query which gives all rows for June, then run the Crosstab query wizard on that. This data is suited well for TRANSFORM.

Comment: yup, I am on a limited resource since the pc I use runs on virtual network, Citrix. I can only access microsoft sites, so yeah. I am going to check tomorrow again if I can tweak it using TRANSFORM. I hope the module I used earlier is not the same as it returns the error "too many rows" something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who are having the same trouble as I am. I made a solution using ***CrossTab***.
Using the Query Wizard is very easy and understandable. Below is the edited SQL query to suit my needs:

```
TRANSFORM format(Sum(MyCopy.[Duration]), "hh:mm:ss") AS SumOfDuration
SELECT MyCopy.[UserID].[FullName], MyCopy.[TL], Sum(MyCopy.[Duration]) AS [Total Of Duration]
FROM MyCopy
Group BY MyCopy.[UserID], MyCopy.[FullName], MyCopy.[TL]
PIVOT MyCopy.[Process Date];
```

Note: For report purposes, its very easy to just extract this query. I did use `format` so that it won't look ugly with the decimals. Apparently, MS Access does not give the answers real numbers, but same percentage. It solves differently when `sum of total duration` passes 24hrs. So I left it on decimal format for correct numbers to appear.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is compile a query of the data you require, and push this into excel, then programmatically build a pivot table in excel, from access.

I use ADO for pretty much everything - so the syntax I've got here reflects this; If you DAO, you'll need to translate it.

```
sql = _
    "SELECT Name, ProcessDate, HandlingTime " & _
    "FROM tbl ... WHERE ..."

GenerateSimplePivot(excel_path&file_name_to_create, sql, 2)


Private Sub GenerateSimplePivot(xname As String, auditData As String, _ pivotColumns As Long)
    Dim ii      As Long
    Dim XL      As Object
    Dim WB      As Object
    Dim WS1     As Object
    Dim WS2     As Object
    Dim rst     As ADODB.Recordset

    'create/assign xl objects
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    XL.Visible = False
    XL.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set WB = XL.Workbooks.Add
    Set WS1 = WB.Worksheets(1)

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open auditData, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly

    For ii = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        WS1.Cells(1, ii + 1) = rst.Fields(ii).Name
    Next

    WS1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    WS1.Columns.Autofit
    WS1.Name = "AuditData"

    For ii = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        'add column formatting logic here, if required
    Next
    rst.Close

    If WB.Worksheets.Count < 2 Then
        Set WS2 = WB.Worksheets.Add(, WB.Worksheets(WB.Worksheets.Count))
    Else
        Set WS2 = WB.Worksheets(2)
    End If

    WS2.Name = "PivotTable"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Dim PTcache     As Object
    Dim pt          As Object

    WS1.Activate

    Set PTcache = WB.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=WS1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)
    Set pt = PTcache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WS2.Range("a6"), TableName:="PivotTable ")

    WS2.Activate

    With pt
        For ii = (pivotColumns - 3) To 2 Step -1
            .PivotFields(ii).Orientation = xlPageField
        Next
        On Error Resume Next
        .PivotFields(1).Orientation = xlPageField
        Err.Clear
        ON Error GoTo [error handler label]
        .PivotFields(pivotColumns - 2).Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields(pivotColumns - 1).Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields(pivotColumns).Orientation = xlDataField
    End With

    WB.SaveAs FileName:=xname
    WB.Close
    Set WS1 = Nothing
    Set WS2 = Nothing
    Set PTcache = Nothing
    Set pt = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing
    XL.Quit

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set WS1 = Nothing
    Set WS2 = Nothing
    Set PTcache = Nothing
    Set pt = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing
    Set XL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is this what you were after?

Comment: I believe this is what the data display is supposed to be like, but I already have a solution for my problem using crosstab query - by that I am able to get the values I needed for computation, then only export that query for reporting purposes. Sorry I haven't posted the answer as I don't have access to any sites in my office. But I will take a look into this instead of exporting the xtab query. Thanks